# Reading on "Economic nowcasting" for a probabilist

Tags: probability, econometrics, networks, power-law

I am about to attend an interview for a postdoc in "economic nowcasting". I am work mostly in probability, particularly complex networks and random graphs.

I am looking for some good reading, so that I can have some understanding of this field, and how it relates to statistics and potentially complex networks and data science.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting textbook would be Newman-Barabasi-Watt's book [The Structure and Dynamics of Networks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691113572) is a classical one.
Also, [Power-law distributions in empirical data](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062)
Clauset-Shalizi-Newman a seminal paper.

Highly recommend to read the manual of [igraph](https://igraph.org) too, it implements some core random networks and community detection algorithms.

Recent Nature paper [Foundations of complexity economics](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42254-020-00273-3) from Arthur reads superb too.